# Swift: How to use "prepareForSegue" inside UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

I have a UICollectionView inside a UITableView, I want to link another ViewController when the UICollectionViewCell is tapped by user. Inside the UITableViewCell, I downloaded all the data from the Internet and stored in an array. I created a Segue by control drag the CollectionViewCell to the new ViewController and chose "Push". Inside the new ViewController, I added an IBOutlet of UIImageView to show the image of the CollectionViewCell when user tapped the thumbnail. Now when I tapped the CollectionViewCell, it goes to the new ViewController, but there is no pics showed. here is my code, any suggestions?

In the UITableViewConroller:

```
import UIKit

class HomePageTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let sections: NSArray = ["latest news", "good news"]
    var posts1: [Posts] = [Posts]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
  if section < sections.count{
        return sections[section] as? String
    }

    return nil

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {
        let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

        tableViewCell.getCategories()
     //   tableViewCell.scrollToNextCell()
     //   tableViewCell.startTimer()


        return tableViewCell

    }
```

and inside TableViewCell, here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage


class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, 

UICollectionViewDelegate {

var posts1: [Posts] = [Posts]()
var posts2: [Posts] = [Posts]()
var categories: [Category] = [Category]()
var selectedPost1: Posts?

@IBOutlet weak var theCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

I download all the data from JSON and put them inside these arrays. inside this class, I also tried to call the function :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("selected")
    self.selectedPost1 = self.posts1

}
```

the print works when I tapped a cell, but I can't use "prepareForSegue" inside this function. I checked and found out that this function can only be used in ViewController, but how can I do that?

And inside the new ViewController, here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!

var posts: [Posts] = [Posts]()
var selectedPost: Posts?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let post = self.selectedPost{
        let thumbnailUrlString = post.postThumbnailUrlString
        let imageUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: thumbnailUrlString)!
        print(thumbnailUrlString)
        postImageView.af_setImageWithURL(imageUrl)
    }
}


}
```

Since when I download the data, I put them into 2 different array, posts1 and posts2. I want to show the corresponding images in the new ViewController. But I just created one "selectedPost" array, I am not sure is that the problem? and I am not sure if I reload the data to the "selectedPost" array, maybe thats why there is no images showing? really hope anyone can give me some suggestions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prepareForSegue:`. What you need to do is have a `var selectedIndexPath` which is set whenever you select a cell. Then in  `prepareForSegue:` you can access the cell and it's properties i.e:

```
HomePageTableViewController: UITableViewController {
   var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      selectedIndexPath = indexPath
   }

   public override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)
      let cell = theCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
      //do what you need to do
   }
}
```

Comment: theCollectionView is inside the TableViewCell, I can't call it in the HomePageTableViewController. what do I need to do? thanks

Comment: I see. Does your tableView need to be the delegate of the collectionView? If not, you can set the viewController to be the delegate of the collectionView i.e. in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` set `theCollectionView.delegate = self.delegate?`

Comment: in the Storyboard, I drag the TableView to the TableViewController's data source and delegate. and drag the TableViewCell as the CollectionView's data source and delegate. so I guess I need the TableView to be the delegate of the CollectionView. then what should I do? Besides, since I drag the segue from the CollectionViewCell to the new ViewController, even if I don't add the "prepareForSegue", when I tapped the cell, it goes to the new ViewController as well. so I am quite confused. thanks

Comment: Are you able to set the ViewController as the CollectionView's delegate (not datasource) ?

Comment: I can drag the CollectionView to the HomeTableViewController, and choose the delegate. sorry I am new to swift, so still learning, not sure if I am doing right.

Comment: Ok so that means that HomeTableViewController is now the delegate of the collectionView. Implement `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath` in the HomeViewController and test if it gets called when you select a collectionViewCell

Comment: I also use : func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let tableViewCell1 = sender as? TableViewCell,
        let postDetailPage = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController{
            
            let selectedPosts = tableViewCell1.selectedPost1
            
            postDetailPage.selectedPost = selectedPosts     
    }
in my HomeTableViewController. what I want is to set the "selectedPosts" I download from JSON to the "var selectedPost" in the new ViewController class, cause now I feel it didn't pass the data.

Comment: the HomeViewController is a class of UITableViewController, I only can use tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        print("selected")
    }
and when I tapped the cell, there is no print.

Comment: `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` won't be called because what you are selecting is a collectionViewCell, so that means that `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath` needs to be called.

Change your class declaration to conform to the UICollectionViewDelegate protocol and then you will be able to implement it  i.e. -----
`class HomePageTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {`

Comment: Ok. Let me try. But I already add this function in my TableViewCell, which is a subclass of CollectionViewDataSource and CollectionViewDelegate. So do you mean I need to add this function in my HomeTableViewController rather than in the TableViewCell?

Comment: Exactly! We're trying to make the viewController the delegate instead of the tableViewCell, but first you need to make sure the viewController conforms to the protocol (i.e `class HomePageTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {` )

Comment: I tried to deleted "didSelectedItemAtIndexPath" in both HomeTableViewController and TableViewCell, when I tapped on the cell, it will still go to the new ViewController. because I drag the segue from the CollectionViewCell(inside the TableViewCell) directly to the new ViewController. What I want to know is how to put data from the CollectionViewCell to the new ViewController.

Comment: You shouldn't delete `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath:`  from your viewController. You need to implement it there. Once you have, can you check if it is being called when you select the collectionViewCell?

Comment: I checked, I added "func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("selected")
    }" inside the HomeTableViewController, when I tapped on the cell, there is no print. so I guess it didn't be called. thanks for your patient.

Comment: I am not sure if I express myself clearly, and maybe you can have a look at my full code, and then reply me. here is the GitHub: https://github.com/guozian/mypracticeapp.git

Comment: There are some files missing from the repo. Can you upload them please

Comment: I have uploaded again, please check the AppYourBusiness.zip file, thanks.

Comment: did you get it? @Lneuner